# Chrome - Would you like to save this password? prompt getting incorrect value

Tags: forms, google-chrome

I have a form that allows users to request an account on a private website, but there is no Username field. Instead, the specs for this project call for the user entering their e-mail address and password/confirm password. There are also fields for the user to enter their state and country.

When the form is submitted, Chrome displays a prompt asking if the user would like to save the password, but it is displaying the value of the state field instead of the Email address field. (The Email address is the actual username of the account).

I understand that Chrome will traverse a form's fields until it finds a field with an id=password, then it will traverse backwards through the fields to find id=username. Since I do not have a field of id=username and Chrome doesn't relate to id=email, it appears to be using the field immediately prior to the id=password field for the username.

How can I force Chrome to use the field with id=email for the username?

```
<form action="POST" src="#">
    <input id="email" type="text" />
    <input id="state" type="text" />
    <input id="country" type="text" />
    <input id="password" type="password" />
    <input id="confirmpassword" type="password" />

    <input type="submit" value="Request Account" />
</form>
```

When submitted, the above form triggers Chrome's to prompt:

```
Would you like to save this password?

Iowa             ********
```

Note that 'Iowa' is whatever value is typed into id=state field, which of course is wrong.

It would be difficult at this point to change id=email to id=username. Is there an alternate way of doing this and keeping id=email?

Comment: If you use labels that are attached to their inputs using the matching for and id attributes, does it make a difference? [Like in this example](http://jsbin.com/becifi/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: I'm going to try this, but I don't think Chrome is looking at the labels. It's either name= or id= and I think it wants username by default. I was just thinking there might be an attribute or property that I can add to the <input> for email.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There seems to be only one solution to this issue. Renaming `id="email"` to `id="username"` doesn't resolve the issue either. It seems like it doesn't matter about the id or the label, browsers use the field immediately preceding the `id="password"` field as the username and so I have moved the two fields together, like this:

```
<form action="POST" src="#">
    <input id="state" type="text" />
    <input id="country" type="text" />
    <input id="email" type="text" />
    <input id="password" type="password" />
    <input id="confirmpassword" type="password" />

    <input type="submit" value="Request Account" />
</form>
```

If anyone knows how I can specify the field used as `username` in the browser's save password prompt (regardless of form field positioning) I would appreciate the pointer!

Comment: Sad to say but I only managed to solve the problem with the approach you suggested :/

Answer (score 3):

Guilherme's solution `display: none` did not work for me, so I applied the following CSS class on extra login field:

```
.Login--hidden {
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;  
  top: -1px;
  left: 0;
  width: 1px;
}
```

I also had to add `tabindex="-1"` to the element, to take it out of the tab-flow.

Still not ideal.

Answer (score 3):

Im running on the same issue here.figured out (Read somewhere else and tested) that in chrome and in chrome only you can set `autocomplete="username"` on the email field. And this will let the browser know what is the correct username field. However this only works for chrome, so Im not using this solution

Documentation:

- https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/form-styles-that-chromium-understands
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete (it's valid html)

Comment: Setting `autocomplete="username"` might solve storage of the value (after  firts login) - but it does NOT help retrieval for a new customer: because Chrome then retrieves the username (and not the email)

Comment: Even when following all the guidelines, and all tips and tricks, Chrome still used the wrong input field for username for its password manager. I ended up changing the other input text to textarea with col=1 and style resize none. Only then Chrome picked up the correct input text as the username,

Comment: Only that answer helped to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Solved putting a hidden field (with display:none) before password and loading it with the login field value:

```
<input id="login" type="text">
<input id="name" type="text">
<input id="browser-friendly-login-field-location" style="display:none">
<input id="password" type="password">
<input id="submit" type="submit" onclick="$('#browser-friendly-login-field-location').val($('#login').val());">
```